# Getting RTSP/1.0 404 Not Found after ANNOUNCE message

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm trying to stream a video with FFmpeg to Gstreamer-RTSP-Server (it's actually a docker that runs the Gstreamer-RTSP-Server).
The OPTION message gets a "RTSP/1.0 200 OK" response. However, the ANNOUNCE message gets "RTSP/1.0 404 Not Found" response.

This the FFmpeg command (which works OK with a different RTSP-Server):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -intra -an -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554/test
```

This is the messages sequence snapshot from Wireshark:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554/test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
User-Agent: Lavf58.20.100

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, ANNOUNCE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, RECORD, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2019 18:23:03 GMT

ANNOUNCE rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554/test RTSP/1.0
Content-Type: application/sdp
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Lavf58.20.100
Content-Length: 287

v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.10
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.20.100
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z3oQHry4FAe0IAAAAwAgAAAHgIA=,aO4PLIs=; profile-level-id=7A101E
a=control:streamid=0
RTSP/1.0 404 Not Found
CSeq: 2
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Sat, 21 Dec 2019 18:23:03 GMT
```

Any idea why the ANNOUNCE message fails ?

The Gstreamer-RTSP-Server is part of a docker, and I guess it runs with a default Gstreamer pipeline parameters - maybe that's can cause the issue ?

Comment: Can't remember from head - perhaps you want DESCRIBE instead of ANNOUNCE? Not sure if announce works without a session.

Comment: When I will try to play the video stream with some RTSP client such as ffplay (with ffplay -i rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554/test), it will send the DESCRIBE message (the full sequence is OPTION --> DESCRIBE --> SETUP --> PLAY).

But when I want to stream the video from the source to rtsp-server, the sequence should be: OPTION --> ANNOUNCE --> SETUP --> RECORD (but the ANNOUNCE fails...)

Comment: Ah, you want to record, I see that seems about right. Actually, I'm not sure the GStreamer RTSP server handles this scenario. I think it's primary purpose is to feed clients with GStreamer pipelines.

Comment: Never mind it should work. `https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-record.c`. Perhaps you need to setup this entry location in the server so that it exists.

Comment: I think Gstreamer should support RECORD since when I send the OPTION request to the server, it response all the supported actions (which are OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, ANNOUNCE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, RECORD, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN).

Comment: However, I still didn't understand your last comment. 
If I run the example you last mentioned, I'll be able to run this command ? 
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -intra -an -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://192.168.1.10:8554/test

Comment: Ideally it does. If it does, your code for the rtsp server may be missing something compared to the example.

Comment: OK thanks for the help. I really appreciated it. I will give it a try (first I need to understand how to run the example)

Comment: Update: as suggested, I ran the test-record "( -v decodebin name=depay0 ! videoconvert ! rtspsink)". And now I can stream video to the server with: ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -qp 10 -an -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test. However, I fails to play the stream with ffplay -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test or with vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/test. I have no idea why...

Comment: Well `test-record` does what it's name suggests. You can send a stream to the server and the server decodes and displays it. It does not offer logic for connecting another remote client. You would have to write that logic yourself..

Comment: It's still a nice progress... Thanks for the help.
Any suggestions for a guide how to continue with this example ? Perhaps, a different "tesp-app", so if I combine two test examples, maybe I can find the full solution for me. I saw another two tests (test-uri.c and test-sdp.c), but I didn't fully understand if they have a use for me.

Comment: Check `https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/master/examples` and read the examples. Maybe some are closer to your use case, or you get an idea from two different ones how to combine them. And also read the documentatio(https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-rtsp-server/index.html?gi-language=c). GStreamer is an SDK after all.

Comment: Thanks, I hope to update with a solution :)